# RegEx with OR. What am I doing wrong?

Tags: regex, perl

I have this script with for some reason always return `-1`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Test::More tests => 4;

is(scrub(''), '-1');
is(scrub('~'), '-1');
is(scrub('undef'), '-1');
is(scrub('a'), 'a');

sub scrub {
    my $a = shift;

    if ($a =~ m/~|undef|/) {
        return -1;
    }

    return $a;
}
```

What I wanted is that it only returned `-1` when `~` or perl's `undef` or empty string `` is given as argument.

Can anyone see what's wrong?

**Update**: based on the replies, this seams to be the right way.

```
sub scrub {
    my $a = shift;

    return ($a =~ m/^(~|undef|^$)$/) ? -1 : $a;
}
```

Comment: /undef/ checks for the string "u","n","d","e","f" and not for an undefined value.  The test should be `is(script(undef), -1);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A regular expression is not the Right Tool for this job. You use the eq operator to test string equality, you used the defined() operator to test for undef.

```
if ($a eq '' or $a eq '~' or not defined $a) {
    return -1;
}
```

BTW, there is a 4th value of $a that will return -1 here, namely when $a is *already* -1.